# Rotation invariant method to compare points on spherical surface

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

Is there any rotation invariant method that I can use to compare the similarity between the three groups of "A" points as shown below?
[image]

Comment: If you had line figures you could stereographically project them into the plane and confirm that the angles of incidence between edges are the same (since this projection is conformal.) Not sure for point sets...

Comment: yes, mostly for scattered points